# How do I remove opposite values from an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a problem where I am trying to create an array of directions in which each direction is not redundant.

```
plan = ["NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"]
```

As you can see most of the values in this plan are redundant and you may as well simply tell the person to go `"WEST"`.

```
plan = ["NORTH", "WEST", "SOUTH", "EAST"]
```

I also want the plan above to return an empty array.

Comment: Have you had a go? We may be able to help you with a current strategy you have?

Comment: @kallax, that won't work, he's not removing redundant values, he's removing value pairs, like north and south

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have to use delete_if here but I can't figure out exactly how to use it. I'm still new to ruby.

Comment: I've tried creating a unique array then subtracting that from the original array. This works for the first problem but not the second.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given an array of directions:

```
plan = %w[NORTH SOUTH SOUTH EAST WEST NORTH WEST]
#=> ["NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"]
```

I would translate the directions into `x` and `y` coordinates:

```
x, y = 0, 0

plan.each do |direction|
  case direction
  when 'NORTH' then y += 1
  when 'EAST'  then x += 1
  when 'SOUTH' then y -= 1
  when 'WEST'  then x -= 1
  end
end
```

`'NORTH'` increments `y`, `'SOUTH'` decrements `y`, same for `'EAST'` / `'WEST'` and `x`.

With the example array this gives:

```
x #=> -1
y #=> 0
```

These have to be translated back to an array of directions:

```
[
  *Array.new(y.abs) { y.positive? ? 'NORTH' : 'SOUTH' },
  *Array.new(x.abs) { x.positive? ? 'EAST' : 'WEST' }
]
#=> ["WEST"]
```

Although this is not the shortest code, it's relatively easy to grasp IMO.

Comment: awesome approach!

Comment: I mean it - love the solution, it's really easy to understand just by reading without even stopping to think about it - I wish I could upvote more.

Answer (score 4):

```
OPPOSITES = {
  'NORTH' => 'SOUTH',
  'WEST'  => 'EAST',
  'EAST'  => 'WEST',
  'SOUTH' => 'NORTH',
}

frequencies = plan.group_by(&:itself).map do |direction, occurrences|
  [direction, occurrences.size]
end.to_h

OPPOSITES.flat_map do |direction, opposite_direction|
  uncounteracted_occurances =
    frequencies[direction] - frequencies[opposite_direction]

  [direction] * [uncounteracted_occurances, 0].max
end
```

Comment: I feel like this solution has gone over my head a little. Thank you!

Comment: @JackKelly I can explain, just point to the part that confuses you. You can try it step by step in the REPL as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
def simplify(plan)
  h = { "SOUTH"=>"NORTH", "NORTH"=>"SOUTH", "EAST"=>"WEST", "WEST"=>"EAST" }
  plan.each_with_object([]) { |direction, arr|
    (idx = arr.index(h[direction])) ? arr.delete_at(idx) : arr << direction }
end

simplify ["NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"]
  #=> ["WEST"] 
simplify ["NORTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST", "WEST"]
  #=> ["NORTH", "WEST", "WEST"] 
simplify ["NORTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"]
  #=> ["NORTH", "NORTH", "WEST"]
```

Comment: I initially had a long-winded conventional answer, then read @stefan's lovely answer, which gave me the idea for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach which should be straightforward to follow. As with my deleted nearly-answer it's considering directions on a numerical 2D-plane but without the unnecessary complexity (pun intended). As a result this is conceptually similar to the excellent answer already posted by @Stefan.

```
def kanye plan
  r = plan.count("EAST")  - plan.count("WEST")
  i = plan.count("NORTH") - plan.count("SOUTH")

  res = []
  r.positive? ? r.times { res << "EAST" }  : (-r).times { res << "WEST" }
  i.positive? ? i.times { res << "NORTH" } : (-i).times { res << "SOUTH" }
  res
end
```

Examples:

```
plan = ["NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"]
kanye plan #=> ["WEST"]

plan = ["NORTH", "WEST", "SOUTH", "EAST"]
kanye plan #=> []

plan = ["NORTH"]
kanye plan #=> ["NORTH"]

plan = []
kanye plan #=> []
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the Argand-Gauss plane to represent the geographical coordinates, where the real part we will tell the north-south movements while the imaginary part the east-west direction. 
In this way it will be sufficient to run a simple sum of complex numbers.

```
plan=["NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"]
dict = {"NORTH"=>1, "SOUTH"=>-1, "EAST"=>(0+1i), "WEST"=>(0-1i)}

# We substitute for each direction a complex number
dict.each{|coord,number| plan.map!{|item| item==coord ? number : item}}
# We run a simple sum
direction = plan.reduce(&:+)  # (0-1i)
puts dict.key(direction)   #=> WEST

re=direction.real
im=direction.imag

if re!=0 and im!=0
  puts "Direction: #{re.abs} #{dict.key(re/re.abs)} #{im.abs} #{dict.key((im/im.abs) *(1i))}"
elsif re!=0 and im==0
  puts "Direction: #{re.abs} #{dict.key(re/re.abs)}"
elsif re==0 and im!=0
   puts "Direction: #{im.abs} #{dict.key((im/im.abs) *(1i))}"
else
  puts "I did not move"
end

#=> Direction: 1 WEST
```