# From Python and learning Ruby coding assistance

Tags: python, ruby

I've been learning Python for the last 6 months and have done over a 100 problem exercises and I am now tryinglearn Ruby and solve these exercises in Ruby. This is the exercise I'm having issues with, as I feel as if I'm over complicating things and yet not doing it the right way. This is the exercise:

A robot is moving on a grid and has starting position (0,0). The robot can be directed to move a given number of steps up, down, left, or right. 
Write a function that takes in a list of instructions and outputs the distance (in a straight line) the robot is from its starting position. The distance should be rounded to the nearest integer.
The instructions are given as a single array of directions followed by a number of steps to be taken in that direction.

In Python I would start something similar to:

```
import math

pos = [0, 0]

while True:

    s = raw_input()
if not s:
    break
movement = s.split(" ")
direction = movement[0]
steps = int(movement[1])
if direction == "UP":
    pos[0] += steps
elif direction == "DOWN":
    pos[0] -= steps
elif direction == "LEFT":
    pos[1] -= steps
elif direction == "RIGHT":
    pos[1] += steps
else :
    pass
```

And the ruby function that I am creating has the following:

```
class robot

 DIRECTIONS = [:up, :left, :down, :right]

  def up
   directions[1] += 1
  end

  def right
   directions[0] += 1
  end

  def down
   directions[1] -= 1
  end

  def left
   directions[0] -= 1
  end

end
```

**What is the simplest and Ruby-way to do this exercise?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little help from Pythagoras and q&a's [from this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39747442/how-do-i-remove-opposite-values-from-an-array/39757353#39757353) I would do something like this:

```
def robot arr
  ups    = arr.map { |d| d.match(/UP\s(\d+)/);    $1.to_i }.inject(:+)
  downs  = arr.map { |d| d.match(/DOWN\s(\d+)/);  $1.to_i }.inject(:+)
  rights = arr.map { |d| d.match(/RIGHT\s(\d+)/); $1.to_i }.inject(:+)
  lefts  = arr.map { |d| d.match(/LEFT\s(\d+)/);  $1.to_i }.inject(:+)

  Math.hypot(rights - lefts, ups - downs).to_i
end
```

*Key techniques and methods:*

[`match`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-match) uses [regex](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Regexp.html) to extract the number from each string-element. `$1` yields the the first capture of the most recent `match` object. [`Math.hypot`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Math.html#method-c-hypot) (thanks @steenslag for pointing this out) calculates the hypotenuse, this is much easier to use than [`Math.sqrt`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Math.html#method-c-sqrt) which requires more calculation.

*Examples:*

```
input = ["UP 5", "DOWN 3", "LEFT 3", "RIGHT 2", "UP 2", "LEFT 1"]
p robot input
#=> 4

input = ["UP 5", "DOWN 1", "LEFT 3", "RIGHT 6"]
p robot input
#=> 5
```

Comment: Wow, you have really simplified this, Thank you. However, the "up","down","left","right" are the direction, the displacement needs to be a number, similar to a number of steps in a specific direction in order to input something like:   [“UP 5”, “DOWN 3”, “LEFT 3”, “RIGHT 2”, “UP 2”, “LEFT 1”], how can I have the numbers as displacement?

Comment: Hi @MorezSA, my bad I didn't read the question properly! OK so I've updated my answer and it should work as required.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have a lot to learn still, but I am getting there.

Comment: The Math module has a hypot method: `Math.hypot(rights-lefts, ups-downs)` .

Comment: @steenslag, thanks Math.hypot(rights-lefts, ups-downs).to_i also works.

Comment: @steenslag that's awesome, I've updated my answer. Thanks for sharing.